# SQLite select number range from sequence without start

Tags: sql, sqlite, range

I would like to ask you for support, how to select from database. My database contains records is following schema.

Meaning of each row is: indexes 0 - 100 belong to aaaa, from 101 to 200 belongs to bbbb and so on.

```
idx       |    string     | ....
---------------------------------
100       |    aaaa       | ....
200       |    bbbb       | ....
300       |    cccc       | ....
```

Few queries to be selected:

- from 50 to 150, aaaa and bbbb to be selected
- from 150 to 220, bbbb and cccc to be selected
- from 150 to 320, bbbb and cccc to be selected
- from 30 to 320,  aaaa, bbbbb and cccc to be selected

Here is what I came with

```
SELECT idx, string,  FROM table WHERE
  idx >= (SELECT MAX(idx) FROM table WHERE idx <= 120) AND
  idx <= (SELECT MIN(idx) FROM table WHERE idx >= 300)
ORDER BY idx ASC
```

Unfortunately this query does not works well with out of range indexes, for example 0 - 500 will result in an empty set.

**EDIT**:
Other example which is closer to real usage follows

```
idx     | string |  ...
-----------------------
125     | aaaa   |
1463    | bbbb   |
5469    | cccc   |
15896   | eeee   |
589774  | ffff   |
```

Comment: I don't get the results for determining which rows need to be chosen.

Comment: Sometimes I need to select rows which contain indexes 20 - 80. Sometimes I need to select rows which contains 120 - 250.

Comment: Yes, you are right, fixed, sory.

Comment: . . Your question makes no sense.  In one place, you say you want to return multiple values.  Then you give examples of only returning one value.

Comment: Your question is confusing.  What is the expected result for each example table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that `:start` and `:end` are the parameters then you can do this:

```
SELECT idx, string  
FROM tablename 
WHERE idx BETWEEN :start AND (:end / 100 + (:end % 100 > 0)) * 100
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eqi16zUtGf56F9d6beTMst/0).

Comment: Thank you for this query. This approach is correct, as long as range of number is at hundreds. But once idx grows by one or two orders, the division by 100 would need to grow appropriately. Isn't there any better way how to handle ?

Comment: So if the range of number is at thousands replace 100 with 1000.

Comment: In general, idx can be number in almost any order, not necessarily aligned to hundreds or thousands. I'm going to update the question.

Comment: This code answers the question as you posted it. If your requirement is different then post a new question instead of changing the current question which invalidates the answers you got.